# Is it better to start learning C# or C++ in the .NET world?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, vb.net

I have some very rusty C++ and lots of C experience, but have done little OO design or coding.  I've started learning C++.NET as that seemed to be the best starting point.

I've hit restrictions in Microsoft's provision with multiple inheritance and extensions, neither work in C++.

Would I be better off starting again with C#, or am I better off using a mixed language approach.  eg. extensions in C#, rest in C++?

I'm still struggling with this->method or that.property and theother::staticthingy or whatever, and this probably is not an issue in C#.  You'll see what I mean as that probably isn't the right way to desribe the difference between '->' '.' and '::'

I'm getting to achieve what I want, but it's taking me 10 times longer than I think it should.

Is C# any quicker?

Comment: Managed C++ is a bit weird and not that widely used in comparison to C#. You'll probably find the going easier with C#.

Comment: Certainly a LOT more examples.

Comment: Could you please add more information to your question? Multiple inheritance is supported by Microsoft compilers. Are you using Managed C++ or straight C++? What do you mean by "extensions"? What are you trying to achieve? This is an important point to understand if c# is a better fit than c++.

Comment: I agree with David, managed C++ was a bit of a mess imo.  Concentrate on C#, and learn the .NET framework/CLR, much to learn there!  I'm still do a very small amount of work on legacy C++ code, but all "new" work (for me anyway) is in C# for the MS world.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed there are many more C# examples than C++

Comment: C# because Jon Skeet can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MS wants you to use C#, so use C#. If your C++ is rusty, you'll end up wasting time learning a difficult language, which is actually a second class citizen in the .NET world.

However, C++ in the .NET world (called C++/CLI) is a wonderful tool to wrap *existing* non-.NET code into .NET classes.

For the multiple inheritance thing, C# supports inheriting multiple *interfaces* (à la Java), which is by far the most useful use case of multiple inheritance.

Comment: The opening is nonsensical, MSFT is a business that puts resources where the most customers find a benefit.  Like any business does.  Customers have chosen C# over managed C++.  It was not obvious ten years ago that this would happen.

Comment: @Hans: True. What I imply by this sentence is indeed that most resources are put into C#. This means that when using C#, you benefit from these resources. Contrast this from C++/CLI which gains almost no momentum from MS.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on going the .NET route I would personally recommend going the C# route. I see a greater number of support for C# related question and more code examples geared towards .NET. That is just from personal experience. C# is the highest traffic tag on stack overflow.

Comment: this is an important point that you raise here.

Answer (score 0):

I think C# is a bit more sane that C++.  However, you're still not going to get multiple inheritance.

That said, be sure to pick the right tool for the job.  If you absolutely need C++ (and this is becoming more rare every day) then stick with it.

Otherwise, save your sanity and move to C#.

Answer (score 0):

if you got good knowledge in C then C# should be more interesting and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Though I believe this is more a [programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) question, here's my $.02.

I would start with C++. Build an appreciation and understanding for memory management, structures, cleanup, etc. then move to .NET. The Garbage Collector (GC) is nice, but going in to a language that's that "loose" with structure and beginning (IMHO) sets for a poor foundation moving forward.

If you understand what's going on in the background, you'll have a better mind set when developing (keeping a conscience mind of memory and resources).

Just my belief, anyways.

Comment: I can't agree. If you want to learn what's behind, learn C, not C++. Learning C++ if you don't plan to use it in the long run is a complete waste of time, since it is a very difficult language which takes **years** (not months!) to learn. And I don't speak about *mastering* C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get into AAA gaming (or a job that requires C++) start learning C++.

Otherwise, C# is much newer and well refined, making it easier/quicker to learn (imo)

Answer (score 0):

C# is a very easy-to-grasp language. I first learned unmanaged C++ a long time ago, and honestly C++ syntax has changed so much since then I don't recognize it anymore. Before I started programming in C# regularly, my previous C-ish language had been Java, and if you know Java, you can learn C# very easily. Also, from a business perspective, C# is by far the most popular .NET language in terms of how many people want C# programmers, as opposed to VB, C++.NET or F# programmers.

In C#, there is no syntactic difference between, for instance, a member of a class referenced by a pointer, and a member of a class instantiated locally, because in C#, pointers, though they exist, are hidden behind a LOT of abstraction. Everything is a "reference" (if it isn't a simple "value type"), and is passed around as such, so referencing a child of an object is always done with dot notation.